# Is it correct to paraphrase "the most" as "one of the most"

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, subjects, superlative-degree, paraphrasing

I just want to know if I have paraphrased the following accurately or is there another way to paraphrase it?

The original sentence is:

> Our previous study  also demonstrated that PCP was the most opportunistic  infection.

The paraphrase is:

> The Authors identified PCP as one of the most predominant opportunistic infections.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't convey the same thing.

> "[...] PCP was the most opportunistic infection."

This means that PCP was the top-most, number one. There are no infections that are more opportunistic than this one.

> "[...] PCP as one of the most predominant opportunistic infections."

This means that PCP was among the top, but usually means that it wasn't #1. Might be #3 or #5. Still a lot, but not the most.

Depending on your goals, it might be alright to use the latter phrase. Just know it doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: @exastris..Thank you for the answer.